# Angular Rxjs: Observable does not display on view

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

I have the following code that is supposed to display the length of an audio file:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.duration$ = fromEvent(this.player.nativeElement, 'loadeddata').pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        return this.convertDuration(event.target.duration);
      }));
  }
```

But it won't display on my HTML that looks like this:
`<div>{{ duration$ | async }}</div>`

What could be the problem here? I tried to subscribe in my component and this works:

```
this.duration$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Initialization: `duration$: Observable<string>;`

---

After looking at @EliyaCohen's demo, I realized that the reason why my code doesn't work is because I have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` enabled. I think my issue now is how to trigger a change detection without calling `detectChanges()` or `markForChange()` if that's possible.

Here is my [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-beaver-xcwr2).

Comment: Any javascript error in console? Does it work if you replace `return this.convertDuration(event.target.duration);` with `return 10;` ?

Comment: No error. Already tried putting a dummy string and same result. As I've said, the `subscribe()` function works as expected so it's weird why it doesn't print in the HTML.

Comment: I can't think of anything without the whole code. `this.duration$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));` is used right after the assignment in ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: That is the entire code. I've added how I initialized my variable. `convertDuration()` returns the mm:ss format of the duration. `this.duration$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));` is below the assignment and I only added that line to test that the observable works. It's not really part of the code.

Comment: Can you try `<div *ngIf="duration$">{{ duration$ | async }} </div>`

Comment: @AshishRanjan I just did. It still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @franco kindly create a stackblitz if possible

Comment: I have added my demo above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work this way:

```js
@Component({
  /* ... */
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  duration$: Observable<string>;

  @ViewChild("video", { static: true }) player: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @Input() source: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.duration$ = fromEvent(this.player.nativeElement, "loadeddata").pipe(
      map((event: any) => event.target.duration)
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `{ static: true }`, since the `video` element does not depend on any conditions, like `ngIf`.

The problem with `ngAfterViewInit` is that the **async pipe** will create its subscriptions **before** this lifecycle hook takes place. This means that by the time `ngAfterViewInit` is invoked, the async pipe will have already figured out its subscriptions, but since this happened before this hook, there was no subscription, so nothing to subscribe to.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This works exactly as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem, so I made [a simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-wildflower-w5w7t?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) that might help (don't mind the errors of codesandbox).

1. I created a `<video>` tag
2. I bound the `video` tag and called it imported it from `@ViewChild`
3. on `ngAfterViewInit` I used the exact code you did, but without `convertDuration` since I'm not sure what it does exactly.
4. I subscribed in the HTML to the observable and it worked.

If you could share a little bit of your code, I might be able to reproduce it.

Comment: I was fiddling around with your demo and I realized where my code differs. I have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` enabled. Here's my version of the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-beaver-xcwr2) that has `OnPush` and that's when it stops working. How can I trigger a change detection here?